# PHP: Best practices when using namespaces

Tags: php

I am using namespaces for structuring my php code (**PHP8**). It looks something like that.

```
<?php
namespace assets\math;

function add($a, $b){
    return $a + $b;
}

function sub($a, $b){
    return add($a, -$b);
}
```

```
<?php
namespace assets\xml;

function existChild($xml){
    return count($xml->children()) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

```
<?php
namespace mainModule;

include_once(PATH_TO_MATH);
include_once(PATH_TO_XML);

class MainModule{
    public function doStuff(){
        // ...
        $c = \assets\math\add(1,3);
        // ...
    }
}
```

So my assets handle some minor stuff, the "intelligence" is focused in my `mainModule`.
But there are different ways to use namespaces. In the example above I used the whole name of the namespace **(1)**:

```
\assets\math\add(1,3);
```

Another approach would be to import every single function I need from other namespaces **(2)**, e.g.

```
use function assets\math\add;
```

Also I could use the whole namespace and then call the function directly by its name **(3)**.

```
use assets\math;

// ...

$c = add(1,3);
```

**(2)** is something I would do in javascript, but what is a good practice for php when using namespaces? What is commonly used or am I totally wrong with my approach?

Comment: In my experience, namespaces are `StudlyCase`, so `Assets\Math`, `Assets\Xml` and `MainModule`. For usage, I rarely, if ever, use the full namespace inline (unless I have to, such as in a view. I prefer Importing via a `use ...;` statement, but I haven't run into a time where I need a partial import (i.e. methodology `(2)` vs `(3)`). I don't know if there's a published list of standards or best practices, and as such this answer might be an opinionated one, so it might not get much in the way of answers.

Comment: With regards to using full names vs short names, there is no standard, it's just personal preference. With regards to naming namespaces and files, see [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). E.g., class `\Foo\Bar\Baz` should be defined in file `Foo/Bar/Baz.php`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky In this case, there would be folders with one single .php file, did I get it right? For instance, I could store `math.php` under `assets/math/math.php` and `xml.php` in `assets/xml/xml.php`.

Comment: Well, PSR-4 pertains to classes in namespaces, not so much naked functions in namespaces. I would recommend putting your functions in classes so that you can use PSR-4 autoloading. So, something like `namespace Asset; class Math { public static function add(...); }` in the file `Asset/Math.php` and `namespace Asset; class Xml { public static function existChild(...); }` in the file `Asset/Xml.php`. And then you'd call them via `\Asset\Math::add()` or `\Asset\Xml::existChild()`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky At first I used classes with static methods, however it happens from time to time that I need a $this reference to call e.g. a method of the own class. In the example above I use the function `add` in `sub`. For this reason I used functions and not a static class.

Comment: Then you just do: `public static function sub($a, $b) { return self::add($a, -$b); }`

Comment: One last question: Should I always use the whole namespace, e.g. `\DataApi\Records\UserRecord::functionName` instead of using the namespace (class) `use DataApi\Records\UserRecord` and calling functions like `UserRecord:functionName` ? Because I would like to use one method in the whole project - but some namespaces might have longer names.

Comment: That's just personal preference. I think most devs prefer the latter use case.